# Convergent series with condition

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

There exists a sequence of strictly decreasing real positive numbers $x_n$ such that its series converges, but the quantity
$$\frac{x_n^2}{x_n-x_{n-1}}$$ 
doesn't converge to zero?

All the famous ones aren't good, but I tried also something different:

$x_n-x_{n-1}=-x_n^2$  is a recurrence formula that describe a sequence, but I don't know if the series converges or not.

Also, setting $z_n$ the partial sum of the $x_k$, we obtain 
$$\frac{x_n^2}{x_n-x_{n-1}}=\frac{(z_n-z_{n-1})^2}{z_n-2z_{n-1}+z_{n-2}}$$
that looks like the discrete derivation, so probably it's sufficient to find a real crescent function with
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=c>0 \qquad \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(f'(x))^2}{f''(x)}\ne 0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make things real bad with 
$$1,1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{8}\dots.$$
(This answers the question as it was put originally. The small modification below answers the revised question.)

To make the sequence strictly decreasing, replace the first $\frac{1}{2^n}$ in each pair by $\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2^{2n}}$.

Comment: ok, my bad, I forgot an hypotesis (in reality I thought it was useless): the $x_i$ are strictly decreasing

Comment: I made a minor modification to make it decreasing.

Comment: It seems to work! Thanks! 
Markov chains will always be grateful to you!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

How about
$$ x_n = \begin{cases} 2^{-n} & n\text{ odd} \\
2^{-(n+1)}+2^{-3(n+1)} & n\text{ even}  \end{cases} $$